# Create new JFrog Artifactory local repository with JFrog CLI

Tags: repository, artifactory, jfrog-cli

How can I create a new Artifactory local repository with JFrog CLI, this means **without** UI?

I use JFrog CLI version 1.34.0.

many thanks

Comment: You have to try first and share codes so community can help you better.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar How would one describe this with code?

Comment: seem my mistake it is command-line client, I thought some sort of programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Since version 1.39.0 the JFrog CLI supports creating repositories using the [repo-create command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Creating/UpdatingRepositories).

**Original Answer:**

The CLI does not support this functionality at the moment. You can do it using the [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateRepository).